# vb.net Dispatcher.Thread doesn't always match up on loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, dispatcher

I'm running the below function and it's a bit hit and miss, sometimes it loops back through and runs `Call ShowProgressDialog(Nothing, Nothing)` other times it just does the `If Me.Dispatcher.Thread Is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread Then` and jumps straight to the `Else`...

```
Private Function CloseDownTheApplication() As Task
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Test whether the thread that owns the control of interest is the current thread...
    ' If it's not, you invoke a delegate referring to the same method via the control of interest.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If Me.Dispatcher.Thread Is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread Then
        Call ShowProgressDialog(Nothing, Nothing)
    Else
        Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf CloseDownTheApplication))
    End If

End Function
```

Some additional info - It's initialised from a Background Worker which is initiated from `worker.RunWorkerAsync()` which works absolutely fine, but it is the reason I need to cross over the threads to run my code.

The `ShowProgressDialog` runs this code block if it matters:

```
Private Async Sub ShowProgressDialog(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim controller = Await Me.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...", "We are baking some cupcakes!")

    Await Task.Delay(5000)

    controller.SetCancelable(False)

    Dim i As Double = 0.0
    While i < 6.0
        Dim val As Double = (i / 100.0) * 20.0
        controller.SetProgress(val)
        controller.SetMessage("Baking cupcake: " & i & "...")

        If controller.IsCanceled Then
            Exit While
        End If
        'canceled progressdialog auto closes.
        i += 1.0

        Await Task.Delay(2000)
    End While

    Await controller.CloseAsync()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

I've googled it to death and all I can find really is a different way to check using `Dispatcher.CheckAccess` but this makes no difference. Also I'm on VS Express For Windows Desktop and using VB.Net.

Comment: Not sure if bumping works here, but... bump